# Как правильно сохранять значения?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как правильно сохранять `int` значения. Вот у меня динамически формируются `int` значения который в зависимости от условия нужно сохранять.

Первая идея была сохранять в `SharePref`, но так я могу сохранить только одно значение, так как каждое последующее значение будет перезаписывать предыдущее.

Потом, я подумал сохранять в `File`, но каждый раз прочитывать файл со значениями и формировать из них массив, тоже вроде не сильно удобно.

Самый идеальный вариант это было б сохранять в `SharePref` `int` массив, но нельзя... Можно сохранять только `String` массив.

Подскажите как правильно можно сделать, чтоб не сильно криво было... А то я чет только криво пока придумал))

Comment: Сохранить массив чисел как массив строк а потом обратно?..

Comment: в локальный JSON или XML

Answer (score 2):

Раз нужно использовать преференс, то можно вот так:

```
public void saveObject(String key, Object object) 
{
    Editor editor = preference.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(object);
    editor.putString(key, jsonStr);
    editor.commit();        
}

public ArrayList<?> loadList(String key, Class<?> class_) 
{

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();  
    String json = preference.getString(key, "");


    try {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
        arrayList.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i), class_));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return null;
    }

    return arrayList ;
}
```

Сохранение:

```
List<int> list  = new ArrayList<>();
list.add ( ...
...
saveObject("MyList", list);
```

Чтение:

```
List<int> clickFilterList = (ArrayList<Integer>)loadList("MyList", Integer.class);
```